# PhpUnit testing elasticsearch results are empty

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, testing, phpunit

I am writing testing methods of my app and in my app I use elasticsearch. When I run a test method which should return values using elasticsearch, the response is always empty. How can I solve the problem? Here is the code I send.

```
public function testGetPosts()

{
    $brand = factory(Brand::class)->create();
    $account = factory(Account::class)->create();
    $post = factory(Post::class)->create();

    $response = $this->actingAs($this->owner)->json(
        'GET',
        ('/api/publish/posts'),
        ['account_id' => [(string) $account->id],
        'skip' => 0]
    );

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Comment: I got what the problem is but I dont know how to solve. Elastic search doesnt index the created post. It shuold be indexed.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but I add there the answer I found for this problem.
All you need to ensure your data is indexed before querying is to call a `refresh` on index you just wrote on.
It forces ES to index data, so you are sure data is there when you query it!
And it is faster than the `sleep(1);` as suggested by author =)

You can find the official ElasticSearch documentation about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html).

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Almost a year, later, I'm sure by now you've moved on.

You stated:

> Elastic search doesnt index the created post. It shuold be indexed
>   Why would it be indexed? Unless, of course you have code to index in your `setUp()`, or your testing against an external ES server and assuming it's always available and contains the exact data you're testing against.

Another solution is to mock the request, since Elasticsearch returns JSON. All we need to do is mock a HTTP request that has a status of 200, and returns JSON. This JSON file we can place in our `tests/` directory, and it will contain the sample results that Elasticsearch would return.

An example test would like this;

```
$handler = new MockHandler([
    'status' => 200,
    'transfer_stats' => [
        'total_time' => 100
    ],
    'body' => fopen(base_path('tests/Unit/mockelasticsearch.json'), 'r')
]);

$builder = ClientBuilder::create();
$builder->setHosts(['testing']);
$builder->setHandler($handler);
$client = $builder->build();
$response = $client->search([
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'body' => [
        [  
            'query' => [
                'simple_query_string' => [
                    'query' => 'john',
                    'fields' => ['name']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);

// Test against the "$response", i.e., $this->assertEquals(2 ...) etc.
```

Then in the JSON file, which you would need to customize based on your index;

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 121668,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "1111",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1111",
          "title": "Some Foo",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "2222",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "2222",
          "title": "Dolor Sit Amet",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "3333",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "3333",
          "title": "Consectetur Adipiscing Elit",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "4444",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "4444",
          "title": "Sed Do Eiusmod",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "5555",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "5555",
          "title": "Tempor Incididunt",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "6666",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "6666",
          "title": "Ut Labore Et Dolore",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "7777",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "7777",
          "title": "Magna Aliqua",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "8888",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "8888",
          "title": "Ut Enim Ad Minim",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "9999",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "9999",
          "title": "Veniam, Quis Nostrud",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test-type",
        "_id": "0000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "0000",
          "title": "Exercitation Ullamco Laboris",
          "timestamp": "2017-08-02T15:45:22-05:00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the effort after a year. I seriously appreciate it. I remember the solution I got here. Since elasticsearch doesn't get the data I created while testing immediately, putting a sleep() method for 1 second had solved the problem. That time gave elastic to get all data created during testing.